# How to pick specific parts from a string?

Tags: java, android

```
String s= "aaaaaaaaaaaBBBhelloDDDeeeeBBBworldDDDffffff";
```

I want to pick the contents between BBB and DDD into a String Array `String[] ss`

That is the words hello and world.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there is. Regex would do it in a fairly simple way. But before that, can we have a look at what you've done and the problem you're facing with it?

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like the most straightforward use of regexes

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching:

```
 String s= "aaaaaaaaaaaBBBhelloDDDeeeeBBBworldDDDffffff";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("BBB(.+?)DDD",Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        ArrayList<String> sa = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
          sa.add(m.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println(sa);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the function substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex).
If you can hardcode the indices.

Answer (score 0):

use `String.split("BBB")` and `String.split("DDD")`

e.g.:

```
String[] splitByBBB = s.split( "BBB" );
/*
in your String: 
splitByBBB[0] is "aaaaaaaaaaa"
splitByBBB[1] is "helloDDDeeee"
splitByBBB[2] is "worldDDDffffff"
*/
```

then you use `split("DDD")` and take the first index:

```
String[] ss = new String[ splitByBBB.length - 1 ];
for( int i = 0; i < splitByBBB.length; i++ )
{
    ss[i] = splitByBBB[i + 1].split("DDD")[0];
}
/*
in your String: 
ss[0] is "hello"
ss[1] is "world"
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = s.split("BBB|DDD");
```